# TomEE / Angular - How to redirect unknown paths from TomEE to Angular Frontend?

Tags: java, angular, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I'm searching the net for days and can't get my question resolved. Hopefully you guys can help me to open my eyes =)

### My Situation:

I am developing an self-contained service with TomEE in the back and an Angular Frontend. Both parts communicate via REST-calls. I defined them with JAX-RS in my Java-Code on the server-side. Angular calls them to let the server run functions.

### My Problem:

If I go to the root of my webpage the Angular-page is loaded and navigation to subpages withing my angular-app works fine.
However, when I use a subpath like `/pages/in/my/angular/app` directly before I called the root-path first I get an 404 error from my TomEE.

### My Question:

How do I configure TomEE / Angular so all paths that TomEE doesn't know, will be redirected to the Angular app and tells the angular-router to go there?

If any code is needed please say so.
Thanks for help.

Comment: https://github.com/bdunklau/LittleBlueBird/wiki/URL-Rewriting-and-HTML5-in-AngularJS

Comment: @peeskillet that looks promising, I check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I already used `javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter` and an embedded TomEE where no web.xml etc. worked (I use an template of my company for self-contained services) I finally managed to got it worked. So here is what I've done:

First of all I managed to added a Regex-check of all uris in my application-filter. When the regex matches the call will be redirected to the root-path of my app.
My angular-frontend has to start from the beginning, the use-cases define it.

Here is my redirect code from my class that implements filter. Code is withing `doFilter`-Method:

```
@Override    
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse 
response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
final String pattern = "(^\/pathToMyApp\/$)|(^\/pathToMyApp\/rest\/.*)|(^\/pathToMyApp\/.*\..*)";
final String baseUri = "/pathToMyApp/";    
if (!httpRequest.getRequestURI().matches(pattern)) {
        logger.warning("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        logger.warning("requestUri: " + httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        logger.warning("uri doesn't match regex, redirecting to root");
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.sendRedirect(baseUri);
        logger.warning("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        return;
    }
}
```

The Regex pattern will allow all calls that either run on `/pathToMyApp/`, `/pathToMyApp/rest/*` or files: `/pathToMyApp/*.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, most known are:

1. custom filter

   ```
       @Override // create a list of angular prefixes stored in frontendResources
       public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse,
                            final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
           if (HttpServletRequest.class.isInstance(servletRequest)) {
               final HttpServletRequest req = HttpServletRequest.class.cast(servletRequest);
               final String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());
               for (String resource : frontendResources) {
                   if (path.startsWith(resource)) { // angular routes
                       filterChain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
                           @Override
                           public String getPathInfo() {
                               return "";
                           }

                           @Override
                           public String getServletPath() {
                               return "/index.html";
                           }
                       }, servletResponse);
                       return;
                   }
               }
           }
           filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
       }
   ```
2. tomcat rewritevalve https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/rewrite.html
3. using web.xml and map front url-patterns to index.html (jsp-file works for instance or just default servlet)

Comment: I will check it out as soon as possible. Do you know if web.xml works with embedded tomee?